# Bazaar locks in Windows

Tags: windows-7, locking, windows-7-x64, bazaar, tortoisebzr

I am new to Bazaar, but that's what is being use at my new job right now. I have installed the latest stable version 2.5.1 on my Windows 7 x64 machine and I can't seem to get it to work.

Every single operation I make, either with the command line tools or the GUI tools end up with the same result. [An error window pops up to tell me the program could not acquire a lock.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaj8W.png)

Every time, the application I'm using will freeze for about 10 seconds, then this shows up and if I click Ignore, nothing happens. My changes are not saved and nothing is applied. If I choose to close the app, I lose all my changes. It even does that when I click the red X to close the application.

In the command line, I try to init a repository and I also get a lock error, but it's different this time. [There's an error with a lock inside the repository I'm trying to create.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmS69.png)

I just can't figure it out at all and I need help.

The version of Bazaar I'm using is 2.5.1 with the bundled Python v2.6.6 and Tortoise BZR.

Comment: Ouch. I see you already filed a bug on Launchpad, well done. https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+bug/1172533 In the meantime, perhaps you could try the 2.6b1 release, both the Python 2.7 based and 2.6 based. Although it's called "beta" officially, it is actually very stable.

Comment: I have tried the 2.6b1 release as well to no avail. Meanwhile, that bug on Launchpad was filed by someone else, though I did leave a comment on it. It appears that user has a space in his user name and that could be the cause of _his_ problem. In my case, I can't do any kind of operation, not even a simple bzr init in command line. I get  lock errors all the time and every operation freeze the application and takes forever to output an error. I am really desperate because that is the VCS we use at new job and I can't get my machine to even check out the code I'm supposed to work on.

Comment: I hear ya. Btw it works fine for me in Windows 7 x64, i386, and Windows XP too. You do have write access where you are trying to do `bzr init`, right? Is there anything else suspicious on that PC? I've been using Bazaar for a long time but I've never seen such issue.

Comment: Nothing suspicious. The box is a relatively fresh install of Win 7 Pro that I've been using for 2 weeks now. And of course, I have write access to everything. I disabled UAC to make sure that this wasn't blocking anything and that wasn't the issue, but it still occurred every time. Does Bazaar install any Registry Keys at all? I looked but haven't found anything that looked like it did. Oh and I even uninstalled it and reinstalled it to c:\bazaar\ in case spaces or parentheses might affect paths and such.

Comment: No, I don't think Bazaar uses registries at all. Your workaround is well explained, it would be better to make it an answer, so that people with similar issue could vote on it and comment on it.

Comment: Thanks. I posted my edit as an answer instead as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've installed bazaar in cygwin instead and have been using that for a couple of days now. But, to be able to use the GUI tools, I had to do a couple of tricks. I got them to work and here's what I did. It's a workaround if anybody else is stuck with the same issue. Basically here's what I did.

Through the Cygwin setup, install the following packages:

- bzr
- python3
- python3-pyqt4
- python-pyqt4 (I wasn't sure which one to install, so I installed both, but I think this one is not necessary.)
- xinit
- libqt4core (I think, but I'm not sure. Can't remember if I had to install it or if it was installed as a dependency with python3-pyqt4.)

Then download the individual **Windows** packages for the bazaar plugins you want to use. In my case I downloaded:

- qbzr
- bzrtools
- bazaar explorer

I installed the plugins under c:\bazaar and the installers put them under C:\Bazaar\2.0\plugins.

In a Cygwin terminal, in my home dir, I created the directory ~/.bazaar/plugins/ and in that directory I made a sym link of every directory under C:\Bazaar\2.0\plugins.

After that, in the cygwin terminal, start up a new X-server using the startxwin command. Then export the DISPLAY variable so that your graphical tools know which X session to output to.

`$ export DISPLAY=:0.0`

Also, in case you get the annoying xterm when you start X, just create an empty file called .startxwinrc in your home directory.

Then, when you enter the commands bzr qlog, bzr explorer, bzr qbzr, the tools should open up through the X server and show up on your desktop. If any dependencies are missing, you will get an error message and you can install the missing package through Cygwin setup.

After that, if you want to use your favourite windows merge tool and editors with bazaar in Cygwin, they won't be able to interpret the Cygwin paths. So instead, I created a ~/bin/ folder and made a few scripts that call my favourite apps and that translate the file paths given as arguments using cygpath -w. Here's an example for p4merge:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" = "2" ]; then

    this=`cygpath -w $1`
    other=`cygpath -w $2`
    /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe $this $other

elif [ "$#" = "4" ]; then
    base=`cygpath -w $1`
    this=`cygpath -w $2`
    other=`cygpath -w $3`
    result=`cygpath -w $4`
    /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe $base $this $other $result

else
    echo "Invalid number of arguments."
    echo "Usage: p4merge.sh <this> <other> or p4merge.sh <base> <this> <other> <result>"
    exit 1
fi
```

I configured my bzr explorer to use that as a diff viewer and merge tool and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but I got the same error today. I solved it by simply deleting the content of the directory "C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\bazaar\2.0\lock"

Happened on a Win 7 x64 machine

Comment: Cool, thanks! I've been using my Cygwin/Bash solution since I posted it and it has worked fine for me. Next time I run into this problem however, I'll try your solution.